# Multiplication of (0,1)-matrix with a (0,1)-vector

Tags: python, matrix, binary

In Python, I want to multiply a binary matrix (each element is 0 or 1) with a binary vector. The size of the matrix is something like 100000 x 100 and the vector has 100 elements. If V and x are respectively the matrix and the vector (initialized as bool), this simple code can do the job:

```
V.astype(np.int8).dot(x.astype(np.int8))
```

My question is: is there a way to do it faster by taking advantage of the very binary nature of the 2 operands? After all, each of the 100000 operations is the sum of the logical AND between one row of V and the vector x.

Thank you for any help.
Patrick

EDIT: Just tried your solution unutbu. Strangely enough, the performance for the 2 methods (int8 et einsum) seems to be similar on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
In [12]: V = np.random.randint(2, size=(100000,100))
In [14]: x = np.random.randint(2, size=100)
In [15]: expected = V.astype(np.int8).dot(x.astype(np.int8))
In [28]: result = np.einsum('ij,j->i', V, x)
```

The result is the same:

```
In [29]: np.allclose(expected, result)
Out[29]: True
```

`np.einsum` is about 3x faster:

```
In [30]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,j->i', V, x)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.92 ms per loop
In [25]: %timeit V.astype(np.int8).dot(x.astype(np.int8))
10 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop
```

Note: Unlike your original code, `np.einsum` returns an array of dtype `int32` in this case.

---

You could try to use `np.logical_and` and `np.sum`, but doing so is much slower:

```
In [45]: result2 = np.logical_and(V, x).sum(axis=1)

In [46]: np.allclose(expected, result2)
Out[46]: True

In [47]: %timeit np.logical_and(V, x).sum(axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 78 ms per loop
```

This might be slower because doing the calculation in two steps 
requires the formation of an intermediate array `np.logical_and(V, x)` of shape (100000, 100). Calling `np.einsum` lets the underlying C++ function compute the result directly.

Comment: Just tried your solution unutbu. Strangely enough, the performance for the 2 methods (int8 et einsum) seems to be similar on my machine.

Comment: That's possible. Performance (even relative performance) of various methods may depend on version of NumPy, libraries used when compiling NumPy (see `np.show_config()`), the OS, hardware, etc.